# How to remove a custom label in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I am a regular geo-cacher and therefore I want to mark certain places on Google Maps to find the location faster when I am playing. I enter the coordinates of the location in the search bar, go to the location, click "Add a label" and save it with a custom name. That works like intended.

After I found a cache, the label is of no use to me any more and I want to remove it again. Most likely I overlooked the option, but I couldn't find how to do this. Removing the whole label overlay is not a solution as I just want to remove specific custom labels which I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hit those **3 dots** and select **Edit list**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I missed the "Your Places" lists. I actually found what I am specifically looking for under "LABELED".